# Join for async function in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have some async functions. Look at the sample below:

```
async def read_database():
    # some code

async def read_web():
    # some code

db_data = read_database()
web_data = read_web()

# do some stuff

# Now here I want to wait for db_data and web_data if the functions did not yet complete.
```

If I used *threading* or *multiprocessing* libraries I would just use join. I don't want to use *await*, because that will not let me do some other stuff while the functions are running. How can I wait for these functions?

Comment: You are aware of `await asyncio.gather()` ?

Comment: No. Let me look it up.

Comment: You should maybe check out simple examples of how to use `asyncio`. Your example makes little to no sense to me. e.g. this post makes things maybe clearer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200122/scraping-urls-asynchronous-including-exception-handling

Comment: @RandomDude I think that is what I am looking for. But I am not sure:
Does the **f** and **g** functions start funning in this line: `tasks = [f(), g()]`
Or in this line: `results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`

Comment: async functions do not run by themselves. They produce "coroutine object", which must be pushed into some event loop, for example asyncio loop

Comment: In this case they start running in the second line. But you shouldn't conclude that `gather` is somehow "starting" them. For coroutines to run, two things need to happen: you need to register them with the event loop, and you need to actually allow the event loop to run. `gather()` does both, but there are other ways - for example, outside the event loop, you could do `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(); loop.create_task(f()); loop.create_task(g()); loop.run_forever()`, and they would also run, without a call to `gather`.